# How to toggle react-navigation if there is two drawer?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have spent most of the time trying to find out how to toggle right Drawer with react-navigation Ref?

currently, it toggles only with left drawer

navigationRef.getParent() or navigationRef.current.getParent() returns undefined

https://snack.expo.dev/@cmark1902/two-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an id to a Drawer.Navigator instance like so:
`<Drawer.Navigator id="LeftDrawer" />`. When calling getParent, you can pass in this 'id' field as an argument and chain the openDrawer() function like so: `navigation.getParent("LeftDrawer").openDrawer()`. This article in react navigation v6 docs explains it perfectly. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/multiple-drawers/